# CSS popup layer size relative to window size

Tags: html, css, popup

Working example of popup i currently using is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/UUZpM/1/

It's based on this solution: http://blog.avtex.com/2012/01/26/cross-browser-css-only-modal-box/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="viewbox popupBoxWrap">
    <div class="vertical-offset">
        <div class="popupBox">
        <form style="height:300px">
        <table>
            <tr><td>key</td><td>val</td></tr>
            ....
        </table>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.popupBoxWrap {
    z-index:40001;
}

.vertical-offset { /* Fixed position to provide the vertical offset */
    position:fixed;
    top:5%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:40002; /* ensures box appears above overlay */
}
.popupBox { /* The actual box, centered in the fixed-position div */
    width:300px; /* Whatever width you want the box to be */
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;

    background-color:white;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.popupBox form {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

But as you can see heigh of this popup is set with fixed value `300px`, i tried to make set it in perecent, but result was unacceptable. I need at least height to be set in **%** of window height. Any idea how to accomplish this task ? Is it possible to do without Javascript ?

Comment: So you want the pop up to take over the whole page? or just set a percentage for the pop up?

Comment: Yes, when i tried to set `%` value, then scrolling was ruined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need that your modal (pop-up) have width and height in % 
this is the simple way. `[http://jsfiddle.net/achr3f/98MBD/][1]`

of course with JS you can make the height (or width)   depend of the window resolution, by changing Css attributes after page load or after resize